# Error in Ridge Regression Gradient Descent (Python)

Tags: python, regression, gradient-descent

I am currently trying to create a code for Ridge Regression using Gradient Descent.

My code goes like this:

```
def gd_ridge(X, Y, beta, iter, learning_rate, lambda):
    m = X.shape[0]
    
    past_costs = []
    past_betas = [beta]
    
    for i in range(iter):
        pred = np.dot(X, beta)
        err = pred - Y
        cost = cost_reg(Yhat1, train_data_Y, lambda)
        past_costs.append(cost)
        beta = beta - learning_rate * 1/m * np.dot(f(X,beta)-Y,X) + lambda/m * beta
        past_betas.append(beta)
```

with l =  regularisation hyperparameter.

But I always end up with an error in my **beta**:

*can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'*

Can anyone help me with this? I've tried different equations and I end up with the same error.

Comment: Your code can not possibly be valid since `lambda` is a Python keyword.

Comment: thanks! i tried to change it to 'l' but the error is the same :(

Comment: i edited the code above to 'l' instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likely you're not passing in `numpy` arrays, but a list instead. Pass in numpy arrays or do `beta = np.array(beta)` in your function.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it and it runs. But, it does not show the right answer i think. It returns only with x-values hence my graph shows only a straight horizontal line.

Comment: @stetu Try debugging and see what's wrong. If it still doesn't work ask a new question with your new problem. Since you're new to stackoverflow, I must ask you not to edit questions with new problems after the first has been fixed, because this makes the old question useless to other future visitors.